# why am i getting a tox import error before the dependencies are installed

Tags: python, django, tox

in my django project, I have a an `__init__.py` file that imports celery, I suspect this may be causing tox to complain.

`/testproj/testproj/ ____init___.py`

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

when I run tox, the tests successfully run, but I see this error.

```
File "/dir/work/testproj/testproj/celery.py", line 2, in <module>
from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
mobilereports installed: amqp==1.4.9,anyjson==0.3.3,appdirs==1.4.0,Babel==2.3.4,billiard==3.3.0.23,cached-property==1.3.0,celery==3.1.24
```

What I find strange is that the import error is above the actual imports where celery gets imported.

Why am I getting this error? Celery is in my `requirements.txt` which is being installed by tox as you can see above, so why would I get an import error before the deps actually get installed?

```
tox.ini

[tox]
envlist = mobilereports
skipsdist = True

[env]
commands = ./runtests.sh 


setenv =
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testproj.settings
    PYTHONPATH={toxinidir}

[base]
deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt

[env:testproj]
basepython = python3
deps =
    {[base]deps}
```

Comment: Well the error specifically states it cannot import `Celery`. You should double check to make sure `Celery` is a method inside of the `celery` library. Case sensitive of coarse.

Comment: If you are using Python 2 at all, add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to your `celery.py` so that `from celery import Celery` isn't treated as an implicit relative import.

Comment: What directory is `tox.ini` in?

Comment: The error is showing it is using python 2.7, but tox is creating a virtualenv with python 3 with all the dependencies, so why would an error be thrown in the first place with python 2.7, i thought the whole point of tox is to create a venv and THEN run tests in it.

Comment: is the solution to change the python path on the box itself to version 3?

Comment: I'm not sure of the best way to get tox to use Python 3. Perhaps install tox from within a Python 3 virtual environment, or use `pip3 install tox`.
 [This issue](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/96) might help. Adding the `from __future__ import absolute_import` might be the pragmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your `celery.py` file to something else. It might be masking the `celery` module installed via requirements (so the `from celery import Celery` line could be importing from the module itself).

Comment: that raises the question - why would it not be masking the celery module installed via requirements on dev and prod.  This issue is only happening when using tox locally on a test box.  I can run unittests against dev and prod (without tox)

Comment: also if i need to go in and tinker with my actual application in order to get tox running, than using tox is not a great solution for this project.  i would prefer any solution other than touching my app.

Comment: The reason it happens with tox is this in the tox.ini: `PYTHONPATH={toxinidir}`